# Need to customize jquery tabs css

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

Hi here i have used jquery tabs and then my output is like

[image]

and i need to get like (Need to remove line below selected tab)

[image]

My code is like

css:

```
<script type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #eef;     
    }
    #tabs {
        width: 95%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
</script>
```

Layout:

```
<div id="tabs" style="min-height:200px;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mission">Mission</a></li>
                <li><a href="#vision">Vision</a></li>
                <li><a href="#noticeBoard">Notice Board</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="mission">
                <p>${homePage.mission}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="vision">
                <p>${homePage.vision}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="noticeBoard">
            </div>
        </div>
```

js:

$("#tabs").tabs();

Can anybody help me doing this

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have changed the default CSS in some point because for default that's the style of the tabs. Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xc8BM/)**

The style that hides the bottom-border for the active tab is this:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
     margin-bottom: -1px; padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```